# How to publish new version of android apk if lost previous keystore.jks

Tags: android

I have an application which was developed in 1 year ago.  Now the client wants to publish a new version with new functionality.  I lost the previous **keystore.jks** file.  How can I publish a new version?

Comment: you can not upload with same package name and different keystore. Now you are in one way **Unpublish the old one and upload new**.

Comment: i can understand but it is important for me and also for programmer . Thanks for your comment and vote.

Answer (score 3):

Refer
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Where it states that

> Warning: Keep your keystore and private key in a safe and secure
>   place, and ensure that you have secure backups of them. If you publish
>   an app to Google Play and then lose the key with which you signed your
>   app, you will not be able to publish any updates to your app, since
>   you must always sign all versions of your app with the same key.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the same keystore, you have to remove the app from the store and re-upload it with a new keystore.

Comment: can it possible with  same package name?

Comment: different package name

Comment: No, I don't think so

Comment: @Suman , if you follow this process you will loose total download and ratings for the application.

Comment: what do you think?How to do this?

Comment: Delete old app and publish new app is only solution by this approach you will lost all old ratings and app users